# why is my app keep executing a function that have already been executed in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences

Ive created an app for muslims that can check whether the user have check in their solat or not. I created a function that can check if the user is late everytime they open the app. For example, now is zohor prayer time, and if they open the app during zohor but did not check in during subuh prayer time, a late function is called which saves the integer 2 in a shared preferences with 'subuh'. ( 2 is equals to late, 1 is equal early and saved when the user check in, 0 is default)
Everything works fine but everytime there is a late prayer time, the late counter keeps increasing eventhough the function only calls when the first time a prayer time is check. My code looks very hard coded because im still new to flutter. Have been stuck in this problem for days now

below is the page which checks the function everytime user opens the app

```
void latecheck(){
    int subuh = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getSubuh();
    int zohor = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getZohor();
    int asar = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getAsar();
    int maghrib = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getMaghrib();
    int isyak = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getIsyak();
    bool checksubuh = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getCheckSubuh();
    bool checkzohor = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getCheckZohor();
    bool checkasar = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getCheckAsar();
    bool checkmaghrib = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getCheckMaghrib();
    bool checkisyak = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getCheckIsyak();

    switch(subuh){
      case 0:
        if (prayerTimes.currentPrayer().index >= 1  ) {
          if (checksubuh == false) {
           setState(() {
             Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).SubuhChecked();
             Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).decreasehealth();
             Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).subuhlate();
           });
          }
        }
        break;
    }
    switch(zohor){
      case 0:
        if (prayerTimes.currentPrayer().index >= 4  ) {
          if (checkzohor == false ) {
            setState(() {
              Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).zohorlate();
              Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).decreasehealth();
              Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).ZohorChecked();
            });
          }
        }
        break;
        }
    switch(asar){
      case 0:
        if (prayerTimes.currentPrayer().index >= 5 ) {
          if (checkasar == false ) {
            setState(() {
              Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).asarlate();
              Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).decreasehealth();
              Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).AsarChecked();
            });
          }
        }
        break;
    }
    switch(maghrib){
      case 0:
        if (prayerTimes.currentPrayer().index >= 6  ) {
          if (checkmaghrib == false) {
            setState(() {
              Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).maghriblate();
              Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).decreasehealth();
              Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).MaghribChecked();
            });
          }
        }
        break;
    }
    switch(isyak){
      case 0:
        if (DateTime.now().hour >= 23  ) {
          if (checkisyak == false) {
            setState(() {
              Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).maghriblate();
              Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).decreasehealth();
              Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).MaghribChecked();
            });
          }
        }
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }

  }
```

One of the functions to stored my prayer check

```
Future<void> subuhcheckin() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    subuh = 1;
    prefs.setInt('subuh', subuh);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> subuhlate() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    subuh = 2;
    prefs.setInt('subuh', subuh);
    increaseLateCounter();
    increaseLateSubuh();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> loadSubuh()  async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    subuh = (prefs.getInt('subuh') ?? 0);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int getSubuh() {
    loadSubuh();
    return subuh;
  }
```

increase late counter and increase late subuh

```
Future<void> increaseLateCounter()  async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    late = (prefs.getInt('late') ?? 0) + 1;
    prefs.setInt('late', late);
    notifyListeners();
  }


  Future<void> loadLate()  async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    late = (prefs.getInt('late') ?? 0);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int getLate() {
    loadLate();
    return late;
  }

  Future<void> increaseLateSubuh()  async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    latesubuh = (prefs.getInt('latesubuh') ?? 0) + 1;
    prefs.setInt('latesubuh', latesubuh);
    notifyListeners();
  }


  Future<void> loadLateSubuh()  async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    latesubuh = (prefs.getInt('latesubuh') ?? 0);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int getLateSubuh() {
    loadLateSubuh();
    return latesubuh;
  }
```

Comment: I see you are not `await`ing all your `Future`s. First, make sure your linter is set correctly, so your compiler can *warn* you when you make those mistakes. Second, it's good practice to not make calls multiple times, when you can make it once and save the results. Making  multiple calls to `await SharedPreferences.getInstance()` is pointless. Save the result *once*. then many of your functions will become sync instead of async and you will have less points in your program to make above mentioned mistakes.

Comment: Please share code for increaseLateCounter(); and increaseLateSubuh();

Comment: @nvoigt can you share an example for it

Comment: @Prashant ive editted the code

Comment: For example your method `getLateSubuh` loads from the shared preferences, *but does not wait until the value is loaded*, instead returning the variable immediately with whatever was in it before.

Comment: @nvoigt ah i understand now, tq very much for your answer and hekp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with

```
int getSubuh() {
  loadSubuh();
  return subuh;
}
```

`loadSubuh()` is an async function. Therefore `subuh` will be 0 when this function returns because `subuh` is not set yet because `loadSubuh()` is not finished yet. To make sure it's set you need to make this function async as well and await the load, so like

```
Future<int> getSubuh() async {
  await loadSubuh();
  return subuh;
}
```

This will cause that `latecheck()` also needs to be async and you need to await there also accordingly.

Another tip unrelated to your error is that you should minimize the number of same function calls if you can. For example instead of

```
    int subuh = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getSubuh();
    int zohor = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getZohor();
    int asar = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getAsar();
    int maghrib = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getMaghrib();
    int isyak = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getIsyak();
    bool checksubuh = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getCheckSubuh();
    bool checkzohor = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getCheckZohor();
    bool checkasar = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getCheckAsar();
    bool checkmaghrib = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getCheckMaghrib();
    bool checkisyak = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false).getCheckIsyak();
```

you should better do

```
    final provider = Provider.of<checkinlist>(context, listen: false);
    int subuh = provider.getSubuh();
    int zohor = provider.getZohor();
    int asar = provider.getAsar();
    int maghrib = provider.getMaghrib();
    int isyak = provider.getIsyak();
    bool checksubuh = provider.getCheckSubuh();
    bool checkzohor = provider.getCheckZohor();
    bool checkasar = provider.getCheckAsar();
    bool checkmaghrib = provider.getCheckMaghrib();
    bool checkisyak = provider.getCheckIsyak();
```

Comment: ive changed the int to future int like you said above however i also have to change the subuh into int subuh = provider.getSubuh() as int or Future<int> subuh = provider.getSubuh() ; this however cause error on the my switch case

Comment: @MuqriHafiy you would need to do `int subuh = await provider.getSubuh()` and also make you `latecheck()` async

Comment: omg it worked haha thank you very much youre my lifesaver, will noted your suggestions and tips for the future. Hope you have a great day!